# Dynamic security for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I'm designing an app in ASP.NET MVC, and the usual way to protect actions is by the attribute `Authorize` which protects an entire action.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Managers")]
public AtionResult Info(int employeeId )
```

However, in our design the application is highly data driven.  An action on one set of data might be allowed, and on another set of data not be allowed.

```
//OK
http://host/Employee/Info/102

//Not OK
http://host/Employee/Info/105
```

What pattern should we use for security for this design?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a derived Authorize attribute to do whatever you want.

```
public class DynamicSecurity : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //go to db
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could decorate your action methods with a custom attribute deriving from the ActionFilterAttribute class, and in the OnActionExecuting method inspect the data in the incoming request, and if anything's not allowed then throw a security exception/redirect/do whatever you require.